# php classes and extended classes

Tags: php, class

I like to ask a question related to php classes! Let's assume I have a clients' table, a streets table and another table called towns. In OOPs I must assume that I have a clients class, a streets class and also a towns class. So every class is related to another one like the following:

**Client:** clientId, clientFirstname1, clientLastname1, clientAddress, clientStreetCode, clientTownCode, clientPostCode.....

**Streets:** streetCode, streetName, townCode

**Towns:** townCode, townName

What I would like to ask is, if I am creating a client record shall I extend one class to another or shall I leave them NOT EXTENDED, and then include them in php as single classes?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: if you think of **CLASS**es existing for the purpose of **CLASS**ifying things, none of those three can really be mutually **CLASS**ified.

Comment: @coderodour classy response

Answer (score 1):

Extending in OOP isn an `is-a` relation. In terms of the three classes `Client`, `City`, `Street`, none of them `is-a` instance of any other of them.

Instead you should just use references. A `Client` has a `Street` and a `Street` has a `City`.

```
class Client {
    /**
     * @var Street
     */
    protected $street;

    // ....
}

class Street {
    /**
     * @var City
     */
    protected $city;

    // ...
}

class City {
    // ...
}
```

Maybe you should also think about introducing a new class `Address`, which contains an reference to a `City` and a `Street`, instead of an `Street` with an reference to an `City`

Comment: Thank you for your answer philipp. I am asking because when I need to read a client record with both streetcode and towncode (NOT streetname and townname) then what I am asking is do I need to get their name from the client class, or from their related class. Sorry for asking ..

Comment: You ask the client class after the Street and City `$client->getStreet()->getCode()`